# Refresh JSON after delete

Tags: javascript, json

I have got following JSON:

```
 "memberValidations":
       [
           {
               "field": "PRIMARY_EMAIL",
               "errorCode": "com.endeavour.data.validation.PRIMARY_EMAIL",
               "createdDateTime": null
            },
            {
               "field": "lastName",
               "errorCode": "com.endeavour.data.validation.lastName",
               "createdDateTime": null
             },
       ]
```

After deleting an object `delete memberValidations[0];`

I'm expecting lastname from `memberValidations[0];` but getting undefined instead? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your JSON snippet is invalid, you'r missing the leading/trailing `{}`. You seem to assume `memberValidations` is a variable, from what I can tell, it's not.

Comment: That's not complete JSON, just for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `delete` will remove the item from the array but it won't resize it so effectively you still have an item at index `0` but it's no longer assigned (`undefined`). From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

To remove the item completely you need to also resize the array e.g.

```
memberValidations.splice(0, 1)
```

Comment: is right, you usually use `delete` to remove items by name from a key/value hash, e.g. `h = {a:1,b:2}` and then `delete h.a` or `delete h["a"]` will leave you with `h = {b:2}`. If you want to remove from an array, splice. If you don't want to remove in place, you can clone and remove, or use underscore/lodash's `_.without()`